# Change one character at a time in a string, don't change the string?

Tags: python

I have a string:

`'ABCDEFGH'`

I want to cycle through the string and, one by one, replace each character with one of 4 characters (1,2,3,4):

```
'ABCDEFGH'
'1BCDEFGH'
'A1CDEFGH'
'AB1DEFGH'
```

etc

```
'2BCDEFGH'
'A2CDEFGH'
'AB2DEFGH'
```

etc and so forth. However everytime I try, I end up altering the original string and my output ends up being strings of 1s!

`'1111111'`

Example code below:

```
letters = 'ABCDEFGH'

s = list(letters)
y = 0 
while y < len(s): 
   s[y] = '1'
   y = y + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than change a list you reuse between iterations, produce a new list each time and replace the one character:

```
for i in range(len(letters)):
    s = list(letters)
    s[i] = '1'
    print(''.join(s))
```

You can combine this with a nested loop:

```
for digit in '1234':
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        s = list(letters)
        s[i] = digit
        print(''.join(s))
```

In essence you are creating the product of `'1234'` and a position from `range(len(letters))`, so you could use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to make that a single loop:

```
from itertools import product

for digit, pos in product('1234', range(len(letters))):
    s = list(letters)
    s[pos] = digit
    print(''.join(s))
```

With a little [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) trickery you could make this a one-liner generator expression to produce all combinations:

```
from itertools import product

all_combos = (
    ''.join([digit if i == pos else c for i, c in enumerate(letters)])
    for digit, pos in product('1234', range(len(letters))))
```

This builds a new list on the fly by iteration over `letters`, swapping out the one character at position `pos` for the digit.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> letters = 'ABCDEFGH'
>>> all_combos = (
...     ''.join([digit if i == pos else c for i, c in enumerate(letters)])
...     for digit, pos in product('1234', range(len(letters))))
>>> 
>>> next(all_combos)
'1BCDEFGH'
>>> next(all_combos)
'A1CDEFGH'
>>> next(all_combos)
'AB1DEFGH'
>>> next(all_combos)
'ABC1EFGH'
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> print(list(islice(all_combos, 10)))
['ABCD1FGH', 'ABCDE1GH', 'ABCDEF1H', 'ABCDEFG1', '2BCDEFGH', 'A2CDEFGH', 'AB2DEFGH', 'ABC2EFGH', 'ABCD2FGH', 'ABCDE2GH']
```

Comment: Thank you! Although all the answers were wonderful yours was the most in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Reinitialize the list each time.

```
while y < len(letters):
  s = list(letters)
  s[y] = '1'
  y = y + 1
  dosomethingwith(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'ABCDEFG'
dig = []

for i in range(1,8):
    dig.append(str(i))
    for letter in string[:]:
        print string.replace(letter,dig[i-1])
```